# Text recognition within images

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, beginner

I am a beginner and need further help to elaborate following problem. I want to "read" text from images. In my problem setting, the text on all the images has the same structure. I found this [solution](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/mobile_intro#optical_character_recognition) by googling about "optical character recognition".

The link mentions that I need an object localization algorithm. How can I implement this in tensorflow?

Thank you!